# Warning switch condition has boolean value

Tags: ios, objective-c, boolean

Displaying the subview with first tap on button at the second am removing subview.Its working fine, but am getting a warning is ***switch condition has boolean value***

```
Bool Selected;


-(void)ageview
{
    switch (Selected) {
        case 0:
            ageview=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(26, 110, 100, 135)];
            ageview.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
            [self.view addSubview:ageview];


            Selected=1;
            break;
        case 1:
            [ageview setHidden:YES];
            Selected=0;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    } 
}
```

Comment: what is `"Bool"` exactly? `Boolean`? `_Bool`? `BOOL`? or some custom type defined via `enum`?

Comment: You shouldn't use switch for bool value. You have to handle 2 cases, so you should use if-else statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Objective-C `switch` statement requires `int` value. But you have provided `Bool` value, because of that it is giving that warning.

And regarding your working code, `TRUE/YES` is equivalent to `1` and `FALSE/NO` is equivalent to `0`.

Answer (score 2):

This warning is generated in 64 bit device. If you change the target device while running the code this warning vanishes.
BOOL is a signed char. You can use Boolean which is an unsigned char. Also the following link might help in understanding BOOL behaviour.
http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/bools-sharp-corners/

Answer (score 0):

First of all this is not the right way checking Boolean condition under switch statement, instead you have to use if else for such type of task.